# Why do I see azure function host for .NET startup with Debug=True when I published as release mode?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

When I look at the startup logs for my azure .NET function, I see the following line:

```
Starting Host (HostId=my-function-app, Version=1.0.11015.0, ProcessId=8308, Debug=True, Attempt=0)
```

I have published the project in release mode and I cannot find out anywhere why this is being set.  I am assuming this is not an issue with my function but for some reason the host is in debug mode.  Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That Debug log doesn't mean your code or the Functions runtime host are running Debug builds. The "Debug" here refers to our own internal mode we use to determine whether the Azure Functions Portal has been connected recently. We track that so we can optimize things for connected debug/develop sessions, and when those sessions are disconnected, optimize for steady state.

So you don't have anything to worry about :)

Comment: One thing I do find is that in this case the EnvironmentName from FunctionsHostBuilderContext is Development despite running in production.

Answer (score 1):

Check your web.config file and make sure

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" />
```

Even though your assemblies are in Release mode, the ASP.net runtime uses this setting to change its behavior. I can't find a current list of changes, but I know it includes serving .debug.js files and enabling additional validation and logging.